# TinyMCE apostrophe

Tags: php, html, tinymce

I am currently using TinyMCE (latest version) as my text editor. It is really great, but there are few issues that I just can't figure out.

The major issue is the apostrophe. **Hello it's me!** Would turn into **Hello it/'s me!**
I somehow fixed it with this:

```
$content2 = $_POST['content'];
$content = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($content2), ENT_QUOTES);
```

Now the problem with this is - it doesn't allow me to add any html code. That's causing tinymce not to work.

Also for some reasone the tinymce align center is not working. It just resets the align back to left side. 
Plus there is some bug with option to add image. If I add `http://website.com/image.jpg`
It would post it as: `image.http://mywebsite.com%20http://website.com/image.jpg/http://website.com/image.jpg/%20`

p.s. Sorry for my bad English. Also sorry if it doesn't make much sense as it is really late. Sorry! :(

Answer (score 0):

Tinymce is a wysiwyg - it uses html already. You can verify this by using the code plugin and getting a view of the html content.

For the apostrophe i do not know. The software that saves the content and retrieves it back might be the problem here.

Comment: I just noticed that on my computer (localhost) everything works perfect. On the website (host) it is not working although the codes are identical. Maybe there is some host related problems? Anyway thanks for replay!

Comment: have you checked if the characters get encoded/decoded somehow before and after getting submitted?